# Symfony $request->files is empty

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload

I have a form in symfony with a `<input type="file" id="appbundle_evento_brochure_upload" name="img_uploader_brochure" class="image_upload">` which is generated dynamically with javascript.

When debugging my request I can see

```
+request: ParameterBag {#9 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "par_1" => array:14 [▶]
      "img_uploader_brochure" => "file_name.jpg"
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#10 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#14 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#13 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
```

I'm using Symfony form builder like this: `$form = $this->createForm(EventoType::class, $evento, [*custom options here*]);` where `EventoType` is my custom type generated on my `Evento` entity.

Why aren't my files in the `request->files` section?

The problem here seems to be that this file is not passed in the request as a file but simply as a parameter.

How should I proceed in order to manage them as `UploadedFile`?

Comment: What does the form tag look like?

Comment: @Shotgun it is built from symfony from builder and it looks like this: `<form name="form_name" method="post">`

the thing I could add is that these input file fields are not generated from the entity but are dynamically added via javascript

Comment: @Leggy7 No, what does the Formtype look like. How do you build the form in symfony

Comment: @Koalabaerchen I'm using `$form = $this->createForm(EventoType::class, $evento, [*custom options here*]);` where `EventoType` is my custom type generated on my `Evento` entity.

Comment: @Leggy7 please add that to your question, with the type, since your error is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 9):

Does the form has enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this attribute in your form html tag:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Or this way with twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'multipart': true}) }}
```

That way, you are allowing the form to upload files